# A large grid of buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the easiest way to make an 8 x 8 grid of buttons with the least amount of code? I know I could use a table and put 64 individual buttons but this seems a little tedious to me. The idea is to have 64 buttons that are all an icon sized picture. Each button will have to be unique somehow. I want each button `on.('click')` to disappear probably by using `.hide()`. I've looked up a few ways to do this none of them are quite helpful and I've started to try to make a 8 x 8 grid of 64 individual buttons but who wants to do that!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: By using a simple `for` loop?

Comment: "What is the easiest way to make an 8 x 8 grid of buttons with the least amount of code? "

Comment: Use 64 floated left divs, with every eighth one having a class that sets the clear property to start a new row. This is not an appropriate use-case for tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it quite easily using a basic loop to dynamically append elements to a container in your document.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Javascript with jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el;
    for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
        el = document.createElement('div');
        $(el).addClass('button');
        $(el).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('removed');
        });
        $('#container').append(el);
    }
});
```

[See this fiddle for a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fY2Lt/)

**Please note**

This example is just one quick way to do it. The buttons are floated next to each other but wrap automatically after all 8 buttons because the container width is set accordingly (8 x (50px + 5px margin) = 440px)

The elements are not really removed when they are clicked. You could do a `this.remove()` instead of adding the `removed` class on click, but in this example it would cause adjacent floats to fall back by one position (for each removed button).

Therefore this example is meant only to help you understand the principles of dynamically changing your document structure by adding/modifying elements on the fly.

Comment: This is the solution I would have implemented also. I probably would have added an ID attribute `i` throughout the loop also.